# Is there PHP auto formatter that will format lines so they don't exceed 120 chars?

Tags: php, formatting, format

As the title say, is there PHP auto formatter that will format lines so they don't exceed 120 chars? It would be really helpful.

Edit: I thought its clear but apparently its not, i ask for auto php formatter like http://www.phpformatter.com/ with function to auto brake long lines up to 120 its a general question and its not any code context in particular.

Comment: without more context, http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php ?

Comment: a little bit of your code in the post would go a long way to avoid all the `clarification` comments, and misfired answers. **[Read all about a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs linked by @Scuzzy:

```
<?php

$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "\n");

echo $newtext;
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox 
jumped over the lazy 
dog.
```

https://3v4l.org/Z563k

You can use `<br>`'s instead of `\n`'s if you like. Or even both!